# Locale import two classes

Tags: isabelle

I want to define classes and locales and combine then to create different types My attempt is given by

```
theory Scratch
imports Main 
begin
class A =
  fixes getA:: "'a ⇒ string"

class B =
  fixes getB:: "'a ⇒ string"

locale CombAB = A + B +
  fixes get:: "'a ⇒ string"
end
```

the results is

```
locale CombAB =
  fixes getA :: "'b ⇒ char list" 
   and getB :: "'c ⇒ char list" 
   and get :: "'a ⇒ char list"
```

but I expected

```
locale CombAB =
 fixes getA :: "'a ⇒ char list" 
  and getB :: "'a ⇒ char list" 
  and get :: "'a ⇒ char list"
```

Why are there three variables `'a,'b,'c` and not just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless told otherwise, Isabelle always derives most general types. In this particular example it has no idea that `A`, `B` and `CombAB` are talking about the same type `'a`, so it just renames type variables to the new ones. You can tell it to use the same type variable by specifying required types explicitly with a clause `for` as follows:

```
locale CombAB =
    A getA +
    B getB
    for
        getA:: "'a ⇒ string" and
        getB:: "'a ⇒ string" +
    fixes
        get:: "'a ⇒ string"
```